How can troubleshoot this error in my react-appwrite application?
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../../utils/AuthContext";
import "./loginPages.css";
const StudentLogin = () => {
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 const { user, loginUser } = useAuth();

 const loginForm = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
  navigate("/protect");
 }
 }, []);

 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = loginForm.current.email.value;
  const password = loginForm.current.password.value;

  const userInfo = { email, password };
  loginUser(userInfo);
 };
 return (
 <div className="login container">
   <div className="wrapper">
     <div className="login-container">
       <div className="login-wrapper">
         <h2 className="login-header">
           <Link to="/protect">Login</Link>
         </h2>
         <form ref={loginForm} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
           <div>
             <label>Username</label>
            <input type="email" className="text-input" required />
           </div>
           <div>
             <label>Password</label>
             <input type="password" className="text-input" required />
           </div>

           <div className="checkbox">
             <label htmlFor="#">
               {" "}
               <input type="checkbox" />
               Remember me
             </label>
           </div>
           <input type="submit" value="Login" className="login-btn btn" />
         </form>

         <div className="or">
           <hr className="bar" />
           <span>OR</span>
           <hr className="bar" />
         </div>
         <Link to="/prtportal" className="other-btn">
           Login as Parent
         </Link>
       </div>

       <footer className="login-footer">
         <p>Copyright &copy; 2023 Azure. All rights reserved.</p>
         <div>
           <Link className="login-footer-link" to="/">
             Terms of Use
          </Link>{" "}
          |{" "}
          <Link className="login-footer-link" to="/">
            Privacy Policy
          </Link>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 );
 };

 export default StudentLogin;

 
//AuthContext page//

import { useContext, useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { account } from "../appwriteConfig";
const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(false);
 }, []);

 const loginUser = async (userInfo) => {
  setLoading(true);

 try {
   let response = await account.createEmailSession(
     userInfo.email,
     userInfo.password
   );

   let accountDetails = await account.get();

   console.log("accountDetails:", accountDetails);
   setUser(accountDetails);
   } catch (error) {
   console.error(error);
   }
   setLoading(false);
 };

const logoutUser = () => {};

const checkUserStatus = () => {};

const contextData = {
 user,
 loginUser,
 logoutUser,
};

return (
 <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
   {loading ? <p> loading...</p> : children}
 </AuthContext.Provider>
 );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export default AuthContext;

I am trying to build an authentication with Appwrite on ReactJS, but I get an error saying             "loginForm.current.email is undefined", and "loginForm.current.password is undefined" when I try to login in the app by sumitting the form, and I don't understand where the error is coming from.
Everything was working fine and I did not run into an error, so I do not think that the error is coming from other files.

I do not see any 

This is embarrassing. I spent the whole time worrying about other problems but my form. Thank you very much. God bless

The error "loginForm.current.email is undefined" occurs because you're trying to access the email input element within the loginForm ref before it's fully initialized.
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = loginForm.current?.email?.value; 
  const password = loginForm.current?.password?.value; 

  if (email && password) { 
    const userInfo = { email, password };
    loginUser(userInfo);
  } else {
    // Handle missing email or password 
  }
};

